# UIButton doing different action ios

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, action, ibaction

I have two navigation buttons(left and right) and two category buttons(for ex. loveCategory and otherCategory). When I select loveCategory I want my navigation buttons to display(in my case Images) only from loveCategory and when I press otherCategory the navigation buttons should be able to display(images) only from otherCategory(that is when I press the left and right button).

Let me know if this is not clear.

here is my code :

```
-(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
UIButton *button=sender;
switch (button.tag) {
    case 1:
        //statements
        break;
    case 2:
        //statements
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

}

-(IBAction)loveCategory {
}
-(IBAction)otherCategory {
}
```

**How do i call an action within another action**

```
-(IBAction)loveCategory 
{ 
  -(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
// Is it possible to call an action within another action?
}
}
```

Comment: @chirag - spelling mistake? lol

Comment: I am not getting you exactly please explain more. What do you mean `only from loveCategory` and `only from otherCategory`. Do you want to different navigation button for different Category ?

Comment: Ok to be more detailed. I have images in database(sqlite) for both loveCategory and otherCategory. And I have two navigation buttons(left and right). After I press loveCategory i use navigation buttons to go left and right to display the images which is fetched from DB, but when i Click on otherCategory and navigate using the  same left and right button(which is in -(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender), I'm getting the images for loveCategory again but not the otherCategory.

Answer (score 1):

Give tag 1 and 2 to your button and try this:

```
    -(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(id)sender {

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 1:
            //statements
            break;
        case 2:
            //statements
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have already done that.. my question is how do i use the NavigationBtnTapped Action to perform someother action? I actually want to call this NavigationBtnTapped method in another -(IBAction)loveCategory

Comment: Just call the relevant method depending on which button has been tapped. What's the problem ?

Comment: How do i call  -(IBAction)loveCategory {   -(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(id)sender // Is it possible to call an action within another action?
}

Answer (score 0):

**AnOther Way is ....**

Give **tag** of both `UIButton`.

such like

```
button1.tag = 101;
button2.tag = 102;
```

Both `UIButton` have same method call.
such like,

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
   if(sender.tag == 101)
   {
     // code for loveCategory
   }
   if(sender.tag == 102)
   {
     // code for otherCategory
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting flag that which category is selected at last by doing this

```
int selectedCategory = 0;

-(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
UIButton *button=sender;
switch (button.tag) {
    case 1:
        //statements
        if(selectedCategory == 0){
           // go left for lovecategory 
        }else{
          // go left for OtherCategory 
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        //statements
       if(selectedCategory == 0){
            // go right for lovecategory 
       }else{
           // go right for OtherCategory 
       }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

}

-(IBAction)loveCategory {
  selectedCategory = 0;
}
-(IBAction)otherCategory {
   selectedCategory=1;
}
```

Is that what you want ?

For calling action within another action

```
-(IBAction)loveCategory 
{ 
  [self NavigationBtnTapped:null];
}
-(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
// Is it possible to call an action within another action?
}
```

Comment: I want to call NavigationBtnTapped within love category like below -(IBAction)loveCategory 
{ 
  -(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
// Is it possible to call an action within another action?
}
}

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.. I created another action called -(IBAction)loveNavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender and tried to call it within (-IBAction)loveCategory { [self loveNavigationBtnTapped:null]; } and its not working..

Comment: What do you mean by `I created another action called` and how its not woking.

Answer (score 0):

another way for that is to have 2 UIButtons and two UIImages however it's not a good way for doing this :D

In the beginning loveCategory's button hidden = NO and it's image hidden = YES, also otherCategory's button = YES and its image is hidden = NO.

When you click on loveCategory's button , loveCategory's button hidden = YES and  its image hidden = NO and also for otherCategory's button hidden = NO and image hidden = YES

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer !

in header file

```
BOOL isLove,isOther;
```

in implemention file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    isOther=TRUE;
    isLove=FALSE;
}

-(IBAction)NavigationBtnTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
if (isLove) {
// Statement
}
else
{
//statement
}
```

If necessary use "else if" to check for multiple buttons.